# Log whether a global variable has been read or written

Tags: c, algorithm

### **Requirement:**

Given a C program I have to identify whether the functions accessing global variables are reading them or writing them.

**Example code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* global variable declaration */
int g = 20;

int main()
{

    /* writing the global variable */
    g = 10;

    /* reading the global variable */
    printf ("value of g = %d\n",  g);

    return 0;
}
```

Executing the above code I want to generate a log file in the below format:

```
1- Global variable a written in function main() "TIME_STAMP"
2- Global variable a read in function main() "TIME_STAMP"
```

---

### Research:

I am cetainly able to acheive this by doing a static analysis of source code as per below logic:

- Go through the c code and identify the statements where the global
  variable is read.
- Then analysis the c code statement to identify if
  it is a read or write statement.(Checking if ++ or -- operator is
  used with global variable or any assignemnt has been made to the
  global variable)
- Add a log statement above the identified statement which will execute
  along with this statement execution.

This is not a proper implementation.

**Some studies:**

I have gone through how debuggers are able to capture information.

Some links in the internet:
[How to catch a memory write and call function with address of write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004945/how-to-catch-a-memory-write-and-call-function-with-address-of-write)

Comment: The *normal* C way would be to use getters and setters and instrument them. C is still rather low level, and it does not even support references, so even through macros I cannot imagine how you could simply instrument assignations...

Comment: If dynamic analysis/instrumentation is an option, tools like [Pin](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/) can do exactly what you want. See "Memory Reference Trace".

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Yes you are right this feature is there in Object Oriented or high level language, it helps a lot in profiling performance enhancement etc... so looking for a implementation in c

Comment: If you need That, C is not the appropriate language...

Comment: Alternatively, but it will no longer be portable, use the low level system calls used by debuggers to step at run time through instructions or even better use a true debugger...

Comment: Yes it looks difficult to implement in C, but lets see if anyone have implemented

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the way i solved this problem:

- I created a utility(In java) which works as below(C program source file is the input to my utility):

  - Parse the file line by line identifying the variables and functions.
  - It stores global variables in a separate container and look for lines using them.
  - For every line which access the global variable i am analyzing them identifying whether it is a read operation or write operation(ex: ==, +=, -+
    etc are write operation).
  - For every such operation i am instrumenting the code as suggested by @alk(https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158928/6160431) and that in turn will generate the log file when i execute the modified source file.

I am certainly able to achieve what i want but still looking for better implementation if anyone have.

For further discussion if anybody want we can have have a chat.

I refer the source code and algos from the below tools:

http://www.dyninst.org/

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool

Comment: _"I am cetainly able to acheive this by doing a static analysis of so [...] This is not a proper implementation."_ Plain ol' `grep` would work as well.

Comment: @black: Yes this is not a proper way, but it solves what i want i would love if you can direct me to a proper implementation. How static analysis can give me a run time result?

Answer (score 7):

Not completely answering your question, but to just log access you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g = 0;

#define g (*(fprintf(stderr, "accessing g from %s. g = %d\n", __FUNCTION__, g), &g))

void foo(void)
{
  g = 2;
  printf("g=%d\n", g);
}

void bar(void)
{
  g = 3;
  printf("g=%d\n", g);
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("g=%d\n", g);
  g = 1;
  foo();
  bar();
  printf("g=%d\n", g);
}
```

Which would print:

```
accessing g from main. g = 0
g=0
accessing g from main. g = 0
accessing g from foo. g = 1
accessing g from foo. g = 2
g=2
accessing g from bar. g = 2
accessing g from bar. g = 3
g=3
accessing g from main. g = 3
g=3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @alk, but how can i identify if it is a read or write call.

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra: I see no (standard?) way to do this. You could detect changes by saving the current value to a temporary variable each time the macro gets "called" and compare to it the next time.

Comment: Yes that is an option i am checking but the problem is, there can be occurrence in which memory will be written but the value will remain the same(Ex: Multiplying with 1(This one can be result of some expression)).